# How do I download a Sheets file then send it to a server in .XLSX format?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drive

I have a Drive with my files and would like to send them to my server for backing up. I would like to convert all Sheets to Excel format (.xlsx). So, I select my file and then click upload button and it goes to myfunction(). In myfunction, I download the .xlsx file and then send the text to my server but then I try to open it with Open Office and I get an error saying the file is corrupted. (I print off the url in the console and when I open that url in the browser it works correctly, though). I download the file in Scripts so that I can make sure it opens, as doing so offline on my server may not open it since it doesn't have proper permissions.

```
function myfunction(file, ext){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + file.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
  var params = {
    method      : "get",
    headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  console.log("url: "+url);
  var txt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getContentText();
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'payload': {
      file: file.getName() + '.xlsx',
      file_body: txt,
    },
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://example.com', options).getContentText();
  console.log("upload response: "+response);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, I am worried about Sheets that are on a team drive or are shared and want to make sure I can download those also.

EDIT:
I've also tried the `getAs(contentType)` but, unfortunately, it tells me that I can only download it as a PDF.

Comment: Could you try `file_body: UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob()`? You can download if you have the download permission.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I get the same corrupted file message when I try to open it.